# sqldf: changes timestamp from GMT/UTC to localtime

Tags: r, sqldf, lubridate

I have the exact opposite problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522270/sqldf-changes-timestamp-from-localtime-to-gmt-utc). `sqldf` is converting dates from GMT/UTC to localtime. How do I prevent this behavior? Note: I use the `lubridate` package to convert the date string to POSIXct.

```
dates <- c("9/12/2010 0:25","9/12/2010 23:22","9/10/2010 1:55")
foo <- data.frame(dates=mdy_hm(dates))
```

returns

```
                dates
1 2010-09-12 00:25:00
2 2010-09-12 23:22:00
3 2010-09-10 01:55:00
```

whereas

```
bar <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM foo")
```

returns

```
                dates
1 2010-09-11 19:25:00
2 2010-09-12 18:22:00
3 2010-09-09 20:55:00
```

Comment: it looks that the output depends of your local. Can you please dput your locals, `Sys.getlocale('LC_TIME')`

Comment: If you use `DF <- data.frame(dates = as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y %M:%H")); sqldf("select * from DF")` it will work but I will look into it further.  For further discussion try: http://groups.google.com/group/sqldf

Answer (score 1):

The help-wiki of [sqldf](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) give an example on how to process Dates. You need to use as to convert the result to a numeric. The result is then given to processMethod to convert it to the desired format.

here an adaption to your example.

```
dates <- c("9/12/2010 0:25","9/12/2010 23:22","9/10/2010 1:55")
foo <- data.frame(dates=mdy_hm(dates))
processDates <- function(data, ...) {
   ix <- grepl("_convert$", names(data))
   names(data)[ix] <- sub("_convert$", "", names(data)[ix])
   data[ix] <- lapply(data[ix], as.POSIXct, 
                      origin = "1970-01-01",
                      tz='UTC')
   data
   }

sqldf("select dates as newdates_convert from foo", method = processDates)

             newdates
1 2010-09-12 00:25:00
2 2010-09-12 23:22:00
3 2010-09-10 01:55:00
```